# Validate String Array In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I use ASP.NET MVC. How can i validate string array in my view model. Because "Required" attribute doesn't work with string array.

```
[DisplayName("Content Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Content name is required")]
public string[] ContentName { get; set; }
```

Comment: How do you want to validate the array ? It must be at least one element ? Or every element should be not null or empty ?

Comment: Implement IValidatableObject on the model and perform custom validation in there.  Alternatively do it within your controller and record the errors using `ModelState.AddModelError()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use custom validate

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < model.ContentName.Length; i++)
        {
            if (model.ContentName[i] == "")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Fill string!");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: You need to check for `null` before doing the for loop

Comment: Our goal not check null value. Need check empty string.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a custom validation attribute : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260177/Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-ASP-NET-MVC

```
public class StringArrayRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid (object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string[] array = value as string[];

        if(array == null || array.Any(item => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use like this :

```
[DisplayName("Content Name")]
[StringArrayRequired(ErrorMessage = "Content name is required")]
public string[] ContentName { get; set; }
```