# Validate String Array In ASP.NET MVC in client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, client-side

This is my first post.

I need string array validation such like below.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Content name is required")]
public string[] ContentName { get; set; }
```

I found [a post which has the same situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495284/validate-string-array-in-asp-net-mvc).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33495692/10882227) and following code helped me so much and I could solve my problem.

```
public class StringArrayRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid (object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string[] array = value as string[];

        if(array == null || array.Any(item => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
[StringArrayRequired(ErrorMessage = "Content name is required")]
public string[] ContentName { get; set; }
```

But now I found an another problem. This validation works only server side. I wish I could have a client validation too. Because it would make my client much happier!!

So would you give me a nice way for this? Waiting for your answers!!

---

Thank you for your help.
I write a short code in my view.

```
$.validator.addMethod('stringarrayrequired', function (value, element, params) {

    let array = value;

    if (array == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!array[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}, '');



$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("stringarrayrequired", function (options) {
    options.rules["stringarrayrequired"] = "#" + options.element.name.replace('.', '_'); // mvc html helpers
    options.messages["stringarrayrequired"] = options.message;
});
```

(Sorry, I'm not fluent in JS...)
And I add id="stringarrayrequired" to my . But it doesn't work.
I also checked html code. When I click the submit button, there should be a class="input-validation-error" or "valid" in input tag for "ContentName", but I couldn't find both of them.

I still need more info... Anyone help?

---

I found a way to solve my problem.

(I changed property name ContextName to Selection)

```
[Display(Name = "Selections")]
public Selection[] Selections { get; set; } 

public class Selection
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "SelectionItem is empty")]
    public string SelectionItem { get; set; }
}
```

I use Selections for , SelectionItem for  and .

As you know, [Required] attribute doesn't work for string[]. So I created a Selection class and changed string[] to Selection[], and applied [Required] attribute to string.

I know that this's not a clean way... I'll use foolproof or something.

Comment: You can look into [foolproof](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=foolproof), which builds the client side, custom validation for you.

Comment: I checked the link, it seems to be a great solution for my problem!! Does this work in ASP.NET Core 2.0??

Comment: Yes, you can use it.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, please don't include the answer in the question. Simply add your own answer at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `javaScript` code in your view:

```
$.validator.addMethod('stringarrayrequired', function (value, element, params) {
    // here return true or false based on checking the input value
},'');


$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("stringarrayrequired", function (options) {
    options.rules["stringarrayrequired"] = "#" + options.element.name.replace('.', '_'); // mvc html helpers
    options.messages["stringarrayrequired"] = options.message;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick responce!! I'll try this code and check how it works.

Comment: It doesn't... Maybe there're some errors in the code I added. I described what I wrote in the question post above.

Comment: Can you share your screen via team viewer please?

Comment: Oh! I found a bit dirty way to solve my problem using only built-in reqiured attribute!! I'll share it with you, after I came back from the job :)